# Bechmark models for Text Classification / Sentiment Classification

Tags: natural-language-processing, word-embedding, text-classification, word2vec, benchmarks

I am currently working on a novel application in NLP where I try to classify empathic and non-empathic texts. I would like to compare the performance of my model to some benchmark models. As I am working with models based on Word2Vec embeddings, the benchmark models should also be based on Word2Vec, however I am looking for some relatively easy, quick to implement models.

Do you have any suggestions?